# Swift: programmatically enumerate outgoing segues from a UIVIewController

Tags: swift, uistoryboardsegue

I want to list the outgoing segues from a UIViewController, as described in [Programmatically enumerate outgoing Segues for a UIViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9206257/programmatically-enumerate-outgoing-segues-for-a-uiviewcontroller), but in Swift. (Swift 2, Xcode 7, iOS8+).

I can do

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let s = valueForKey("storyboardSegueTemplates")
    print("switchingVC: segues: \(s)") 
}
```

and that produces output like

```
switchingVC: segues: Optional((
    "<UIStoryboardPresentationSegueTemplate: 0x1754a130>",
    "<UIStoryboardPresentationSegueTemplate: 0x17534f60>",
    "<UIStoryboardPresentationSegueTemplate: 0x17534fc0>"
))
```

but I struggle to produce anything after that. I can't find any definition of the `UIStoryboardPresentationSegueTemplate`. How can I persuade Swift to tell me what's inside it? How can I find the segue `identifier`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this  `valueForKey("storyboardSegueTemplates")` is **UNDOCUMENTED** property and `UIStoryboardPresentationSegueTemplate` is **UNDOCUMENTED** class. Beware of rejection from App Store if you are uploading application to App Store.

If you want to use this in your in-house projects, use as following

```
for template in (valueForKey("storyboardSegueTemplates") as? [AnyObject])! {
    if let identifier = template.valueForKey("identifier") as? String {
        print("identifier - " + identifier)
    }
    else {
        print("no identifier for \(template)")
    }
}
```

Found from https://github.com/JaviSoto/iOS9-Runtime-Headers/blob/master/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIStoryboardSegueTemplate.h

Comment: Excellent! That works, thanks very much, especially for the github link.

Comment: It may work, but beware of App Store approval process

Answer (score 0):

As per Swift 4.2 and from https://stackoverflow.com/a/35060917/1058199.  Thanks /johnykutty.

```
import UIKit

extension UIViewController {

     // Segue aids in Swift
     @objc func isValidSegue(_ segueId: String?) -> Bool {
        let filteredArray = (value(forKey: "storyboardSegueTemplates") as? NSArray)?.filtered(using: NSPredicate(format: "identifier = %@", segueId ?? ""))
        let isValid = (filteredArray?.count ?? 0) > 0
        return isValid
     }

     @objc func segues() -> Array<Any>? {
        let segues = self.value(forKey: "storyboardSegueTemplates")
        return segues as! Array<Any>?
     }

    @objc func segueNames() -> Array<AnyHashable> {
        var segueNames = Array<Any>()

        let filteredArray = (value(forKey: "storyboardSegueTemplates") as? NSArray)?.filtered(using: NSPredicate(format: "identifier != nil" ))

        for template in filteredArray! as [AnyObject] {
           if let identifier = (template.value(forKey: "identifier") as? String) {
               segueNames.append(identifier)
            }
            else {
                segueNames.append("no identifier for \(template)")
            }
        }

        return segueNames as! Array<AnyHashable>
    }
}
```

I know my use of predicates could be better, but Swift is such a PITA when dealing with iterating arrays.  Please feel free to improve this.